# I am trying to add jquery plugin functionality to dynamically built form

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use the datepicker plugin with a dynamically built form.  When I build the form statically with the class datepick the jquery function works fine but when I try to use the same with a text input build using jquery append it does not work.
Here is the code I am using.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="Monroe Community Hospital" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsstuff/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsstuff/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jsstuff/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jsstuff/timepick/wvega-timepicker-cc21378/jquery.timepicker.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../empinc.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mch.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsstuff/timepick/wvega-timepicker-cc21378/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#addform").click(function(){
                $("form").append('<div class="incident"></div>');
                $("div.incident").append('<label class="title">TO BE COMPLETED BY THE SUPERVISOR</label><br />');
                $("div.incident").append('<div><input type="text" id="incidate" name="incidate" class="datepick" /></div>');  
            });
        });
        $(function(){
            $(".datepick").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
   <input type="button" id="addform" value="Add form" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the Add form the form does build but I don't get the datepicker calender.
If remove the jquery append function and use the same elements in a static form it works.

Comment: You just have to initialize plugin once elements are added into the DOM. So target them specifically and call datepicker for these elements inside click handler. Now be aware, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Don't edit the answer into your question - instead, answer your own question (this is perfectly OK on StackOverflow)

Comment: Tried to add the answer but since I am a new member the app would not let me because I did it under the allotted time.

Comment: Fair enough... In this case, waiting produced a good answer, so I suggest you accept it when you are able!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIDDLE:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/UW5nU/4/**

use the delegate way of doing it. Take the reference of already existing element. it can be anything body or the nearest element to the dynamically added content. The way you are adding dynamic elements is not correct. please change your code as below.

```
$("#addform").on("click",function(){
    var formContent = "<div class='incident'>";
    formContent += "<label class='title'>TO BE COMPLETED BY THE SUPERVISOR</label><br/>";
    formContent += "<div><input type='text' name='incidate' class='datepick'/></div></div>";
    $("form").append(formContent);
});

$('form').on('focus',".datepick", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** `ID` attribute should be unique. So remove the `ID` in your datepicker input

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the hint.  Here is the change in the function.  I inserted the datepicker function after the append like you mentioned.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#addform").click(function(){
                $(".incident").remove();
                $("form").append('<div class="incident"></div>');
                $("div.incident").append('<div><label class="title">TO BE COMPLETED BY THE SUPERVISOR</label></div>');
                $("div.incident").append('<div><input type="text" id="incidate" name="incidate" class="datepick" /></div>');  
                $(function(){
                    $(".datepick").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks